# How to check data key is present in below response?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I am using ObjectMapper.framework in swift and successfully mapped all value. That is my code

```
class CompetitionListModel: Mappable {
var active: Int?
var channel: String?
var competition_type_id: Int?
var country_id: Int?
var created_at: [String: String]?
var ends_at: String?
var id: Int?
var name: String?
var logo: String?
var order: Int?
var parent: Int?
var updated_at: String?
var data: [AnyObject]?


required init?(_ map: Map) {
    mapping(map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    active <- map["active"]
    channel <- map["channel"]
    competition_type_id <- map["competition_type_id"]
    id <- map["id"]
    country_id <- map["country_id"]
    created_at <- map["created_at"]
    ends_at <- map["ends_at"]
    name <- map["name"]
    logo <- map["logo"]
    order <- map["order"]
    parent <- map["parent"]
    updated_at <- map["updated_at"]
    data <- map["data"]


}
}
```

and Here is my response which i mapped

```
   {
    active = 1;
    channel = fieldhockey;
    "competition_type_id" = 2;
    "country_id" = 2;
    "created_at" = "2014-09-19T14:45:43";
    "ends_at" = "2099-09-19T00:00:00";
    id = 31;
    logo = "cf78a0a5-9ee2-4419-87e7-90b2eacf6ff5.png";
    name = Fieldhockey;
    order = "-2";
    parent = 0;
    "updated_at" = "2015-09-10T09:30:33";
},
    {
    active = 0;
    channel = "fh-eurohockey-u18m-championship2";
    "competition_type_id" = 2;
    "country_id" = 2;
    "created_at" = "2015-07-02T18:03:50";
    data =         {
    };
    "ends_at" = "2099-12-31T00:00:00";
    id = 112;
    logo = "a19945fd-a0db-485f-809d-d6078e7fbfe8.jpg";
    name = "EuroHockey U18 Championship II, Boys, 2015";
    order = "-2";
    parent = 31;
    "updated_at" = "2015-09-10T09:26:56";
},
```

I am getting this value by this code

```
var arrOperation: [CompetitionListModel] = []
```

and getting value from arrOperation by this 
    Print(self.arrOperation[0].data)

but you can see in the response that data key not present some times in this response and some times its present. So i have to check that data key is present or not, But i mapped this key also which is always present in model class. so i am checking  by this code

```
     if  let keyExists = self.arrOperation[indexPath.row].data {
      print("key is present")
    }
    else{
        print("key is not present")

    }
```

but data key always present in model class its printing nil value. So please give me any idea that how can i identify that key name of data is present in array or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
for dict in self.arrOperation {
    if  let keyExists = dict["data"] {
        print("key is present")
    }
    else{
        print("key is not present")

    }
}
```

Try this code. For my dictionary which has a data key in it, this code works fine

Comment: self.arrOperation is also a object of model class please look my code and i did same for this                                                                                if  let keyExists = self.arrOperation[indexPath.row].data {
      print("key is present")
    }
    else{
        print("key is not present")

    }

Comment: Because you are using simple array but i am using model class array which always have data key. Please look into my code above you will get all info.

Comment: What you have is NSArray type. Change it to Array<Modal> type

Comment: var arrOperation:Array<Modal> = [Modal(data: "Some data"), Modal(data: nil)]